# how can I dismiss keyboard when I click enter in textview

Tags: objective-c

I am beginner of iPhone I working on textview when click enter key of click on return button on keyboard at that time keyboard is not dismiss but enter key appear in next line. but I have require when I write something and enter the key and at that keyboard is directly dismiss so, give any suggestion and source code.

Answer (score 1):

use this in TextView Delegate-

```
 - (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
 {

    if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"])
    {
       [textView resignFirstResponder];
       return NO;
    }

return YES;
}
```